# Long enumerations with roman alphabet. Get aa, ab, ac instead of aa, bb, cc after x, y, z

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Similar to [this unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/1713167/when-lettering-rather-than-numbering-footnotes-can-ms-word-2003-use-a-z) about footnotes in MS Word.

When using an ordered list in LibreOffice Writer, the counter is incremented as:

`a, b, c, ..., z, aa, bb, cc, ..., zz, aaa, bbb, ccc, ..., zzz, ...`

However, I would like to have:

`a, b, c, ..., z, aa, ab, ac, ..., az, ba, bb, bc, ..., bz, ...`

Going into the property panel *"Bullets and numbering"* > *"Customize"* does not show an option to achieve this.

Can I personalise my numbered list in the way I want?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47iJh.gif)?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes! How did you get that? :-)

Comment: On my side (version 7.5.1.2), this is the default see [my setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFgCX.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user Reddy Lutonadio for spotting the problem.

I was editing someone else's `.doc` document.
I don't know if they changed this property or if it is the default when editing `.doc` documents (for compatibility with MS Word), but the value of property *"Number:"* in settings *"Bullets and Numbering"* > *"Customize"* was `a, .., aa, .., aaa, ...`.
Changing this to value `a, b, c, ...` solved the problem.

**Update:** this is definitely a problem with `.doc` and `.docx` documents. In fact, if I change the list numbering to `a, b, c, ...`, close the document and re-open it, it gets reverted back to `a, .., aa, .., aaa, ...`. When saving in `.odt` format, instead, it works perfectly.

Comment: You should accept your answer. You are allowed to do it.

Comment: Only 2 days after posting it, it seems! (I got this pop-up when I tried.)